# C# self reference a method

Tags: c#

can I self reference from within a method, without using the method name (for code maintenance reasons this may cause a future bug)

```
void SelfRef(string _Input){

    if (_Input == "route1"){

        //route1 calls route 2

        SelfRef("route2"); //call self


    }else if (_Input == "route2"){

        //route2 ends
    }
}
```

i would like to not write the word "SelfRef" again and make the function immune to future changes?

Comment: "immune to future changes" <-- that's not an issue unless you're hard-coding literals.  If a future developer is going to change the name of the method, they'll right-click on it and select "refactor" > "rename" and it will automatically change everywhere.  If you have developers who are manually renaming symbols one-by-one, then that's a different problem.

Comment: You want to make a recursive function? I dont think that there is any other way to do it

Comment: You might be able to hack something together using reflection and a StackTrace.  But that would be an exercise in what is possible, not practical.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? If your method starts with an `if` that tests a parameter, then you actually have two separate sections of functionality nestled inside one method, so refactor them out as two methods.

Comment: If you need to recurse (you don't), then just call yourself in the most obvious way. Anyone who changes a method name without using the refactor tooling for changing a method name will likely cause problems irrespective of whether the method is recursive or the method call happens far far away.

Comment: @roryap: _" If you have developers who are manually renaming symbols one-by-one, then that's a different problem"_ even then you have to fix the compiler error that tells you where you also have to change the name.

Comment: @TimSchmelter -- That's true.  The only thing I'll add is that you can get into trouble if your manual change merges two previously-distinct symbol names into one accidentally.  No compiler error.  The refactor>rename will prevent you from doing that if there's an existing symbol with that name.

Comment: +1 Not because I think you're going about this in a smart way at all, but just because I like the question for other reasons. Namely, I believe it could be useful for an anonymous method to self reference for the purpose of removing itself as a handler from an event. Haven't tried yet to see if that actually works but I imagine it would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self referencing (probably via reflection) and recursing seems quite long winded when a loop would be sufficient here:

```
void SelfRef(string _Input){
    while(true)
    {
        if (_Input == "route1"){

            _Input = "route2"
            continue;

        }else if (_Input == "route2"){

            //route2 ends
            break;
        }
        //break?
    }
}
```

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain what's wrong with this pragmatic solution?

Comment: It's taking bad code and making it worse. Remove the loop noise and the `else` in front of the second `if` and the functionality remains the same.

Comment: I know what you mean, however, I expect OPs logic is considerably more complex that the code presented, so I've simply presented a generalised solution that replaces the recursion with a loop.

Comment: it's clearly all opinion but i really like this one, it's inline with what i am doing

that guy doesn't like it but if one of my routes fires i don't want to check the others starting from the last one, i want it to loop

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it's possible:

```
void Foo(int bar)
{
    Console.WriteLine(bar);
    if(bar < 10)
        MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Invoke(this, new object[] {++bar});
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Finished");
}
```

but **please never ever use code like this** (it's ugly, it's slow, it's hard to understand, it will not work if the method is inlined).

Since you probably use an IDE like Visual Studio, renaming a method should never ever be an issue; and even if you rename the method manually you probably hit a compile time error.

Comment: Does `new StackFrame().GetMethod()` guarantied to return current method in case of inlining? Why not `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()`?

Comment: @PetSerAl No, it's not. `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()` also does not work correctly when the method is inlined (because of the jitter or tail call optimation).

Comment: `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()` have `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]` and AFAIK it also prevent inlining of caller method, so `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()` should return correct value. In my system that `public static object TestInlining2() => MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod();` return correct value, while that `public static object TestInlining1() => new StackFrame().GetMethod();` is not. Can you demonstrate the case where `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()` will not return correct value?

Comment: @PetSerAl It's not only the `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]` attribute that prevents the inlining (such methods can still be removed due to tail call optimation). It's the `DynamicSecurityMethod` attribute that also prevents the inlining of the caller. I guess you can say that `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()` will be safer than `new StackFrame().GetMethod()`, but in the end, that actually depends on the runtime, which is outside of the control of your code (there are more runtimes than Microsoft's .Net).

Comment: @PetSerAl Nonetheless, I changed my answer to use `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()`. Thank you very much for the hint.

Answer (score 8):

> I would like to not write the word "SelfRef" again and make the function immune to future changes?

As others have said, you should simply use renaming tools if you are planning to rename a method.

But it is an interesting challenge to make a recursive function that does not refer to the name of the function. Here's a way to do it:

```
delegate Action<A> Recursive<A>(Recursive<A> r);

static Action<A> AnonymousRecursion<A>(Func<Action<A>, Action<A>> f)
{
    Recursive<A> rec = r => a => { f(r(r))(a); };
    return rec(rec);
} 

Action<string> SelfRef = AnonymousRecursion<string>(
    f => 
        input => 
        {  
            if (input == "route1")
                f("route2");
            // and so on
        });
```

Notice how field `SelfRef` nowhere refers to `SelfRef` in its body, and yet the recursion is very straightforward; you simply recurse on `f` instead of `SelfRef`.

However I submit to you that this code is far, far harder to understand and maintain than simply writing a straightforward recursive method.

Comment: Further reading for those interessed: [Anonymous Recursion in C#](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wesdyer/archive/2007/02/02/anonymous-recursion-in-c.aspx)

Comment: @sloth: Hah, I was just about to add an edit saying to look there. Of course I always crib from Wes whenever I talk about the Y combinator. He explains it very well.

Comment: The link @sloth mentioned died due to link rot, but luckily it is in the Wayback Machine https://web.archive.org/web/20140425162950/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wesdyer/archive/2007/02/02/anonymous-recursion-in-c.aspx just like the post from Eric Lippert it refers to https://web.archive.org/web/20140425163114/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2006/08/18/706398.aspx and the referred "Definite assignment" C# language documentation https://web.archive.org/web/20140427071518/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691172(VS.71).aspx

Google needs to index the Wayback Machine better (:

Answer (score 2):

You can create extension like this

```
public static void RecursivelyCall(this object thisObject, object [] param,  [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string methodName = "")
{
    Type thisType = thisObject.GetType();
    MethodInfo theMethod = thisType.GetMethod(methodName);
    theMethod.Invoke(thisObject, param);
}

public static void RecursivelyCall(this object thisObject, object param, [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string methodName = "")
{
    Type thisType = thisObject.GetType();
    MethodInfo theMethod = thisType.GetMethod(methodName);
    theMethod.Invoke(thisObject, new object[] {param});
}
```

So you can use it for recursive call

```
private void Rec(string a)
{
    this.RecursivelyCall(a);
}
```

But, to be honest, i don't think it is a good idea, because

> function immune to future changes

doesn't worth losing code readability.

Comment: Liked this answer the most. Even If i do agree to the fact that it shouldn't be needed for a recursive function.

Answer (score 2):

Now let's just make it clear that the technical term for "self-referencing" is *recursion*. And let's start looking at the problem.

You want to write a recursive method but don't want to "mention" the method name because of maintainability reasons. When I saw this I was like, "what editor are you using?". Maintainability reasons? You mean when you change the name of the method the code breaks?

These problems ca be easily fixed by using an IDE. I suggest you to use Visual Studio Community 2015. It is free and offers a wide range of features. If you want to rename a method, do this:

1. Right click the method name.
2. Select "Rename" in the context menu
3. Type whatever name you want it to be.
4. Press Enter

And you will see that magically, all the references to the method has changed their names!

So you don't need to turn the whole recursive method into a loop or something. You just need to use the right editor!

Answer (score 0):

There's no construct in C# to refer to the method that you're in and call it with different parameters.  You *could* examine the call stack to find the method *name* and use reflection to invoke it, but it seems pointless.

The only type of bug that you would be "immune" to is renaming the method.  In that case, the build will fail and you will quickly have an indication that something is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using reflection using [MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getcurrentmethod(v=vs.110).aspx)  and it's the fastest way that I know of. Certainly faster than using Stacktraces.
You can change your code as follows:

```
void SelfRef(string _Input){

    if (_Input == "route1"){

        //route1 calls route 2

        MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Invoke(this,new []{"route2"}); //call self

    }else if (_Input == "route2"){

        //route2 ends
    }
}
```

Don't forget `using System.Reflection` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

> **You are using recursion, not self reference**

A function (method) calling itself is called as a recursive function and this concept is called as recursion. What you essentially have, is a recursive function called as `SelfRef` that takes a string as a parameter. It calls itself if the parameter is equal to `"route1"` which is a string.

> **Method reference is passing a method to another method**

Method references (as called in other languages) is called as *delegates* in C# and that is used to pass a function itself to another function. This is mostly used to implement callbacks, i.e., event handlers. For example, you might see this code in events.

```
public class DelegateExample
{
    public delegate void MyDelegate();

    public void PrintMessage(MyDelegate d)
    {
        d();
    }

    public void PrintHello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello.");
    }

    public void PrintWorld()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("World.");
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PrintDelegate(new MyDelegate(PrintHello));
        PrintDelegate(new MyDelegate(PrintWorld));
    }
}
```

There you see, you are passing a function as a delegate.

> **Use enums if you know what routes are available already**

Never use strings for communicating between objects or withing the program, only use them for interacting with the user. The best bet (if the routes are pre-known) at the time of writing the program, then use enumerations for this purpose.

Comment: too lazy for writing all the objects in my system with enums, i considered this but it made code too un-managable (at the moment)

i have the option later and i would have to change a dictionary in a parent class to use enums.

thanks though i don't think any answer has been wrong or not clever

Answer (score 0):

Calling a function by name does not cause a code-maintenance problem.

All modern development environments (e.g. Visual Studio) will automatically update every usage of that function's name, when someone renames it.

If you want to make the function immune from future changes, keep the source code to yourself.